# Cloning an Android Application

Tags: android

I made an application for android, but I need to create copies of the same application. I'll have to change the package name, and also all other generated files (/ bin) to the new name of the application.

The divergence between the two applications (the original and copied), in addition to those already mentioned, will be only the strings and styles files.

Is there any simple way to do this? (Maybe creating a library, I do not know exactly how to do this)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your difficulty is in this case. You'd just make a copy of your project folder and then import it into Eclipse as an existing project. In your Android manifest you would modify the package name, and your strings.xml would be modified for the new values (as well as your styles XML files).

Comment: So I'm doing something wrong, because I've done this several times. And always showing errors when I fix one, another appears ... And when they finally end up errors, the application stops when starts... All files should be renamed when I change the manifest file?

Comment: This time i made all changes before the import. But the generated files, it keeps generating the name of the old package.

Comment: Refactoring variable and class names in Eclipse is a breeze. On the Mac, hold down `Command+Option+R` (`Alt+Shift+R` in Windows) and click on a variable or class name and then change the name of that variable, and it will change every instance of that variable name to the new name you provide.